# Are amantadine and rimantadine MOAs unknown to evolution?

Tags: evolution

Are any natural (human or otherwise) antiviral mechanisms similar to the antiviral mechanisms of amantadine and rimantadine, or are these mechanisms undiscovered by evolution? Are drug researchers discovering completely new mechanisms to attack viruses?

http://www.rapidreferenceinfluenza.com/chapter/B978-0-7234-3433-7.50014-1/aim/mechanisms-of-action-of-antivirals

The mechanism by which antiviral drugs (amantadine and rimantadine) interrupt the replicative cycle of influenza is illustrated. M2 inhibitors prevent the M2-mediated acidification of the interior of the virus while it resides in endosomes and the subsequent uncoating of the viral genome, thus inhibiting viral replication. Neuraminidase inhibitors (NAIs) prevent cleavage of sialic acid residues and thus newly formed virus cannot be released from the cell surface to infect adjacent cells; also, virus particles remain associated to one another.

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE. It is an interesting question, but I don't know if there are any experts on animal virus life-cycles in this group. In terms of evolution and discovery, there are definitely pharmaceutical companies (the ones I've heard of were based in Japan) who maintain cultures of purified soil microbes, and then assay the microbes' used culture media for "natural" compounds that affect a lucrative biological process.